# jQuery - removeClass that starts with

Tags: jquery

Now I want to set different classes for different zoom levels in google-maps. Now it only adds the class and does not removes the class which starts with `zoom-` what am I doing wrong here? :

```
  // setMarkerSize by different zoomLevels
    if (z === 16) { $('.marker').removeClass("[className^='zoom-']").addClass('zoom-16'); }
    if (z === 17) { $('.marker').removeClass("[className^='zoom-']").addClass('zoom-17'); }
    if (z === 18) { $('.marker').removeClass("[className^='zoom-']").addClass('zoom-18'); }
```

Comment: It work. See https://jsfiddle.net/rnjgdspv/

Comment: @Mohammad - In your context class is not removed it adds at the last. As per rule it takes the second class will override the first one

Comment: @JqueryKing what is wrong with my code I don't get it

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer Perhaps you can use only class name in `removeClass()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) takes class names only, not selectors.

You can do this instead:

```
var $el = $('.marker');
var classList = $el.attr('class').split(' ');

$.each(classList, function(id, item) {
    if (item.indexOf('zoom-') == 0) $el.removeClass(item);
});

$el.addClass('zoom-' + z); // zoom-16, zoom-17, zoom-18 etc.
```

Comment: `startWith()` support in upper version of browser. For example version 41 of chrome. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: what do you mean by takes only class names not selectors?

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks! Changed it to `indexOf` :)

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer A class is only a string, not an element which has attributes etc. A selector like `$("[class^='zoom-']")` returns **elements**. `removeClass("[className^='zoom-']")` won't do anything because there is no class named *[className^='zoom-']*.

Comment: @Midas thanks man appreciate it, but this is working for one zoom level :) if I add it for each zoom level it does not work

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer How so? After the `$.each` you can write `$el.addClass('zoom-' + z);`

Answer (score 3):

This removes all existing zoom classes. Add the new class at the end.

```
var z = 18;
var items = [16, 17, 18];

$.each(items, function (ind, val) {
    if (z === val) {
        $(".marker").removeClass(function (index, css) {
            return (css.match(/(^|\s)zoom-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        }).addClass('zoom-' + val);
    }
});
```